# Setting WPF GridView Column Width programatically after user manual set

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'd like to be able to collapse/uncollapse a `ListView` `GridColumn` via a user right-click on the column header. The following is a minimal example that accomplishes that, but stops working as soon as a user manually resizes the column (via clicking and dragging the margin). Why is that? What can I do to allow both manual user-resize and the collapsing/uncollapsing I want?

(It stops working in the sense that the column no longer responds to rightclicks)
. In the debugger I can see that after the user resizes the converter is no longer called, so perhaps the binding to width disappears? Why?)

**MainWindow.xaml** (header omitted for brevity)

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>       
        <local:ColVisToWidth x:Key="ColVisToWidth"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ColVisible, Converter={StaticResource ColVisToWidth}}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="MyHeader">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonUp">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ToggleColVis}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ToggleColVis = new RelayCommand(() => { ColVisible = !ColVisible; });
            ColVisible = true;
        }
        public RelayCommand ToggleColVis { get; set; }
        private bool colVisible;
        public bool ColVisible
        {
            get { return colVisible; }
            set { colVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged("ColVisible"); }
        }
        public List<string> ListItems { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "First", "Second" };

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

**Converter**

```
public class ColVisToWidth : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return 120;
            }
            else
            {
                return 15;
            }
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially the ColumnWidth property value is set to a binding expression, with the intention that the effective value will change as soon as the binding source changes (`ColVisible` property). Hover, as soon as an user does a UI resize, it forces the ColumnWidth to have a new value - some fixed number, which overrides the initial binding expression. Then when the binding source is changed, the column is no longer aware of the change, as the binding is no longer active. MVVM is cool, but I fear that the column resize in `GridView` is not very compliant to the pattern, as there is no suitable API for customizing the way in which the resize is processed. Thus I would suggest that you rewrite the trigger action to call a command that sets the `Column.Width` directly instead of using an intermediate bound proeprty.

Comment: Sadly, I think you're right. I gave up on MVVM/binding approach and just used a direct call to the Width in code-behind. That seemed to do the trick.